# Computational issue in root finding

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am tutor for an economics student and he gave me the below expression to solve for $s$ (which has been a past exam problem) which stands here for some economic object. It is in the context of utility maximization, so from a mathematical standpoint an easy exercise. I was irritated as I found myself quite some time later still on the problem, not yet solved for $s$.

$$\frac{d\mathbb{E}[U]}{ds} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{y_0 - s}} + \beta(1+g)\Big(\frac{p}{\sqrt{y_1 + (1 + g)s}} + \frac{1 - p}{\sqrt{y_2 + (1+g)s}}\Big) = 0$$
I **know** that these kinds of algebraic manipulations are elementary and with some time and paper you get $s$ but my **question** explicitly addresses the time situation in an exam, i.e. you got 10 minutes to do it. Is there some accessible trick or shortcut to solve for $s$ here that I don't see? Because the way I would have approached it I would have never been able to do it in 10 minutes.

Comment: Oh... this would be quite frustrating of a problem to tackle head on... :(

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but couldn't you integrate both sides with respect to $s$? All summands on the RHS have rather neat looking antiderivatives.

Comment: @Nephry, I believe (pending confirmation from the OP) that the student is  trying to maximise $E(U)$ or more precisely $E(s)$ and has already carried out the part where he/she's set it to be stationary with respect to zero, so that the problem is now reduced to finding the root $s$ which will (hopefully!) be a maximum and not a minimum!

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar Oh you're right! I actually misread the last equation. Whoops, sorry! :)

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar, that's right. The objective is to find the $s$ which maximizes the expected utility. Usually this is a routine task.

Comment: I haven't done it, but you can move the first term to the right and square both sides.  That gets you down to one term with square roots.  Isolate it and square again.  When you clear the fractions you get a fourth degree polynomial in $s$.  There is a formula for solving those, but it is a mess.  People usually go in for numerics instead.  On an exam the constants may be chosen carefully so there is cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

You have an equation of the form $f(s)=0$ in terms of some other (presumably) known entities. I'm assuming that $\beta$ is a constant and not a function of $1+g$. It doesn't matter if it is - we'll just need to establish conditions on its continuity, if so.

This can be solved with a simple Newton-Raphson iterative approach. You would start with an initial guess, calculate the derivative of $f$ with respect to $s$ and update the initial guess with

$$s_{k+1}=s_{k}-\frac{f(s_{k})}{f'(s_{k})}$$

and repeat the procedure until $|f(s_k)|$ drops below some acceptable tolerance.

You can verify that this is actually a maximum of $E$ by checking the sign (should be negative) of $f'(s_k)$.

Comment: But this is symbolic, doesn't that only work for numerical values? I am not too familiar with Newton-Raphson (not to mention that this is not at all feasible in a 10 minute exam situation in an economics course)?

Comment: Well, if you could post the functional form of the specific entity that needs to be maximised, that would help. If it's purely symbolic, then maybe all the exam is checking is whether the student knows how to solve the problem, not actually plug in numbers. In this case, the expression for the derivative of $f$ as written may be all that's needed.

Comment: Well, the original functional form is just the antiderivative of the above expression. Yes, the student is only asked to find $s$ for the most general case, i.e. all $p, i, b, y_1, y_2, y_3$ unspecified.

Comment: Given the expression, I don't see how it could be resolved to a tractable form for $s$, leave alone in 10 mins!  What is the specific phrasing of the problem on the exam?